# Associated model is not fetched in CakePHP find

Tags: cakephp

I am experiencing an odd behaviour:

In the `$results['capital']` each contained model is fetched (therefore, CapitalCategory, CapitalCategory->Category and Picture) for the Capital model.

But in the `$results['category']` the Picture model is not fetched (only Capital and Category are fetched) for the CapitalCategory model.

I have attached a screenshot for clarity:

[image: screenshot]

What could be the problem? Where should I look? Thank you!

**EDIT**

Here is the output for the `$results['capital']` array,

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [Capital] => Array
            (
                [name] => N'Djamena
                [id] => 81
            )

        [CapitalCategory] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => Ciad
                        [category_id] => 2
                        [capital_id] => 81
                        [Category] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Ţară
                            )

                    )

            )

        [Picture] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [picture] => http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1270/879755600_126f8824db_s.jpg
                        [capital_id] => 81
                    )

            )

    )
```

and here is the output for the `$results['category']` array (I've put only one record since they are similar):

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [CapitalCategory] => Array
            (
                [value] => America de Sud
            )

        [Capital] => Array
            (
                [name] => Asuncion
                [id] => 56
            )

        [Category] => Array
            (
                [name] => Continent
                [id] => 1
            )

    )
```

Comment: can u posted ur model relationships ... i think capital belongs to picture. so dont contain particular field.. change your code like this // contain=>array('Capital'=>array('Picture')) // first try lie this.. if its  coming then add ur conditions but dont add particular field

Comment: Capital hasMany Picture which belongsTo Capital. I've tried to remove the conditions and fields, but the same results. It is very weird because, as posted above, the first part of the array retrieves everything I need, and the query is built identical to the second one.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem was that CakePHP expects to have all foreign keys in the `fields` array. Therefore, after I have added the `'CapitalCategory.capital_id'` in the `fields` array, the Pictures are shown. Still don't get why the first query worked while this one not, but I'm glad I figured it out.

Comment: Odd. I rarely use the fields option so it didn't occur to me.